# how to close last firefox tab?

Tags: firefox, browser

How to make firefox actually close last tab when you press Close Tab?

If you close last tab - tab and firefox will be closed, but if you open firefox again - that closed tab will open again instead of new tab.

In chrome it will start with new tab.

In all browser restore session is checked

Example video: https://gfycat.com/UnhealthyGleefulBlacklab

Comment: Do your *Preferences* have *"Restore Previous Session"* checked?

Comment: added example video chrome vs firefox (37 sec). https://gfycat.com/unhealthygleefulblacklab

Comment: @AlexanderMyravjev - Screenshot(s) are easier to work with on our end instead of inaccessible video files.

Answer (score 0):

The option is in the settings to *restore previous session. You should untick this.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are suggesting is the solution to the author's problem.  You should [edit] your answer and specify what the solution is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

*"In all browser restore session is checked"*

Don't do that, **uncheck restore session.**